# How can I support more than one resolution/language on WP7/8?

Tags: xna, c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want that my Windows Phone game runs on the following three resolutions: 480x800, 768x1280 and 720x1280. And maybe later on 1920x1080.
But in the XAP file information, it's just written "Resolution(s) WVGA". What can I support more resolutions than just WVGA?

In addition, I want to support more than one language. At the moment, I can just choose English in the Dev Center menu, but I want to support French, Spanish and German too. How can I support French, Spanish and German? I don't know how to add these languages.

I uploaded my XAP file in the Dev Center and it gives me the following informations:

> Select a XAP above to view or edit its Store listing and other info.
>
> XAP version number  1.0.0.0
>
> XAP details detected from file
>
> File name WindowsPhoneGame2.xap
>
> File size 167 KB
>
> Supported OS 7.1, 8.0
>
> Resolution(s) WVGA
>
> Language(s) EnglishNorthAmerica
>
> Capabilities ID_CAP_NETWORKING
>
> XAP's Store listing info
>
> A XAP file can contain multiple languages. Select a language to add Store listing info specific for that language.
>
> English
>
> Description for the Store:

Comment: XNA doesn't support any resolutions above 800x480 on windows phone. You have to use MonoGame to be able to run the game on HD resolutions.

Comment: But I run my game in the WVGA, WXGA and 720P emulator in Visual Studio. Is MonoGame the only way to support multiple resolutions in an XNA game? How can I solve the language problem? At the moment, I can just choose English in the Dev Center menu, how can I add the other languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the multi language support, you are looking for something called *localization* , it's a common process used almost in every software development that have more than a single language, here is a special tutorial for [How to: Create a Localized Game on XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff966426.aspx) .

For the multi resolution issue, as Homer_Simpson said (lol), you cannot use resolutions above 800x480 on windows phone with XNA, and in case you moved to MonoGame, as far as i know, there is no magic trick to make such a thing, you have to build it yourself, game engines like unity3D use something called "Virtual Resolution" (World scale and position in unity), the whole principle is about using your own resolution for the whole development, and then scale all the objects based on the target resolution, i myself always use percentage to scale and set positions, specially for GUI cause even unity3D use current screen resolution when it comes to gui,so my suggestion would be to make the whole game in 1 resolution, then calculate the percentage of each object size and position relative to your resolution,

> Example :
>
> Resolution = 800x600 Object = Width=120;Height=80;
>
> 120 = 15%    of 800
>
> 80  = 13.33% of 600
>
> based on that, you have now to change your object parameters to this :
>
> Object.Width  = (Screen.width * 15 )/100
>
> Object.Height = (Screen.Height * 13.33)/100
>
> if you saw some HTML or CSS codes, you'll notice that they also use
>   percentage to place and scale everything
>
> *PS :  sometimes when i was coding GUIs i needed to do the same thing for X & Y*