# Where is the LocalizedFontProcessor in XNA?

Tags: xna, c#

I tried [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff966426.aspx) to localize my XNA Windows Phone game, but I can't find the `LocalizedFontProcessor` in the drop-down list. Why is the `LocalizedFontProcessor` missing in the drop-down list? What is wrong?

In this picture you can see that the `LocalizedFontProcessor` is missing in the drop-down list:

[image]

Is there another way to localize a Windows Phone game?

**Edit: Here is my LocalizedFontProcessor class**

```
namespace LocalizationPipeline
{
[ContentProcessor]
class LocalizedFontProcessor : ContentProcessor<LocalizedFontDescription,
                                                SpriteFontContent>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a font description into SpriteFont format.
    /// </summary>
    public override SpriteFontContent Process(LocalizedFontDescription input,
                                              ContentProcessorContext context)
    {
        // Scan each .resx file in turn.
        foreach (string resourceFile in input.ResourceFiles)
        {
            string absolutePath = Path.GetFullPath(resourceFile);

            // Make sure the .resx file really does exist.
            if (!File.Exists(absolutePath))
            {
                throw new InvalidContentException("Can't find " + absolutePath);
            }

            // Load the .resx data.
            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

            xmlDocument.Load(absolutePath);

            // Scan each string from the .resx file.
            foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlDocument.SelectNodes("root/data/value"))
            {
                string resourceString = xmlNode.InnerText;

                // Scan each character of the string.
                foreach (char usedCharacter in resourceString)
                {
                    input.Characters.Add(usedCharacter);
                }
            }

            // Mark that this font should be rebuilt if the resource file changes.
            context.AddDependency(absolutePath);
        }

        // After adding the necessary characters, we can use the built in
        // FontDescriptionProcessor to do the hard work of building the font for us.
        return context.Convert<FontDescription,
                               SpriteFontContent>(input, "FontDescriptionProcessor");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It's good to keep separate topics in separate questions, but this question is really a comment on an answer to your [previous post](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/66291/how-can-i-support-more-than-one-resolution-language-on-wp7-8).  This is why you shouldn't ask two questions in one; now the previous topic is confused and difficult to follow up on.

Comment: I think that tutorial instructs you to _create_ the `LocalizedFontProcessor`.  (Subheading "To extend the FontDescriptionProcessor class")  Have you completed that step?

Comment: I added my LocalizedFontProcessor class. Why is the LocalizedFontProcessor missing in the drop-down list? I tried to add more references but it didn't helped. I can add the complete project if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your content project (`LocalizationContent`) in Solution Explorer. Select "**Add Reference**".

**Add a reference to your pipeline project (`LocalizationPipeline`) to your content project.**

Make sure the pipeline project is built. Right click it and select build.

Your `LocalizedFontProcessor` should now show up in the Content Processor list.

(You might also have to make your `LocalizedFontProcessor` class `public`, I'm not sure. Also, you can give it a nice name by setting it in the attribute: `[ContentProcessor(DisplayName = "My Localized Font Processor")]`.)

Comment: Thanx. It works.